# Can't Capture Full Screen of iCarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem to capture full screen of [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). it can capture only index of Carousel only .

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(caputureView.bounds.size);
    [caputureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: What is `caputureView`? Be sure you're right - debug.

Comment: clearly entered what you want and what you used in input and carousel view datas

Comment: @DO Sunhour: Did you tried giving hardcoded size of screen..? Try capturing window.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (void) getFullScreenScreenShot
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIView* superView = appDelegate.viewController.view;
    CGRect fullScreenFrame = superView.frame;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fullScreenFrame.size, YES, 0.0f);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0f, 0.0f);
    [superView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImageView* screenShot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenShot.image, 1.0);
    NSString* previewFileNamePath = [[CPFileManager documentsPath] stringByAppendingString: @"image.jpg"];

    if ([imageData writeToFile: previewFileNamePath
                    atomically: NO])
    {
        NSLog(@"See filename:%@", previewFileNamePath);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", previewFileNamePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: It still can get only index iCarousel only .... have anyone got this problem as me ?

Comment: i edited my answer. i'm getting screenshot for full screen without any problem